# Chern number for nonintracing hamiltonian while bands crossing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, chern-simons-theory, topological-phase

Is it possible to define and calculate chern number for two bands while they're crossing each other?

Comment: If you're referring to the cumulative Chern number of the two bands together, the answer is yes. All you need is that the two bands are spectrally isolated from all other bands.

Comment: thank you, I found the answer and I agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, here is the formula. To appeal to a wider audience, let us assume translation invariance so that we work in momentum space. Say the projection onto the two bands is $P(k)$, then the Chern number associated to $P$ [is](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.51.51) $$ \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2\pi}\int_{\mathrm{BZ}}\operatorname{tr}(\mathrm{d}P \wedge P\mathrm{d}P) = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2\pi}\int_{k \in [0,2\pi]^2}\operatorname{tr}(P(k)[\partial_{k_1}P(k),\partial_{k_2}P(k)])\mathrm{d}k_1\mathrm{d}k_2 \,.$$

Comment: Does the same formula hold for  $n>2$ bands as well? Can we have an arbitrary number of band crossings too, as long as we keep that set of bands gapped from the rest?

Comment: Yes, the rank of $P$ is of no relevance here.